# .NET Core Webjob does not publish when deployed through CD in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-webjobs

I have a dot net core 2.0 console app which I need to publish in Azure as webjob through continuous build and deployment in VSTS. I have created a web app already in Azure and defined CI and CD tasks in VSTS for the console app's project.

The issue is that whenever these tasks run, webapp gets deployed successfully but the webjob does not get deployed. However, it gets deployed when I use the artifact (zip folder created after build process) and upload it manually to Azure webjob section.

I think deploying the artifact using powershell script might be a solution but I have tried **zipdeploy** API of Kudu as well but to no use. Can someone please help or point me to a reference for extracting the artifact generated from build process and deploy it using CD tasks so that the webjob gets published alongwith webapp.

Answer (score 1):

With general web application, if you link web job project to the web (right click web app in Visual Studio > Add > New Azure WebJob project/Existing project as WebJob), you can refer to these steps below:

1. Create a new build definition
2. Add NuGet Tool Installer task
3. Add NuGet restore task (Path to solution, packages.config: ***.sln)
4. Add Visual Studio Build task (MSBuild Arguments: /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\")
5. Add Publish Artifact task (Path to publish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory))
6. Queue build
7. Create a new release definition
8. Add Deploy Azure App Service task (Package or folder: {web app zip file path}; Choose Publish using Web deploy)

Otherwise:

1. Create a new build definition
2. Add NuGet Tool Installer task
3. Add NuGet restore task (Path to solution, packages.config: ***.sln)
4. Add Visual Studio Build task (/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish
5. Add necessary task to build web job project (e.g. Visual Studio build)
6. Add Copy Files task to copy web job’ build result to appropriate folder in web app published folder ($(build.artifactstagingdirectory)) (App_Data/jobs/continuous for continuous webjobs or App_Data/jobs/triggered for scheduled and on-demand WebJobs)
7. Add Archive Files task (Root folder or file to archive: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory); Archive file to create: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip)
8. Add Publish Artifact task
9. Create a new release definition
10. Add Deploy Azure App Service task (Package or folder: {web app zip file path}; Choose Publish using Web deploy)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Additional points for your reference : 1) I do not have a solution file to build, I have only csproj file. So, I am providing path to solution as ***.csproj (hopefully this is correct) 2) in place of steps 2,3,4, and 5, I am using .net core build and publish tasks (since this is a .net core application). So, where do I provide build arguments in this case? 3) I added copy and archive steps to the build process after .net core build and publish tasks which I was missing earlier. Still, web app gets published successfully but not the webjob.

Comment: Regarding Core app, you need to copy web job's build result to appropriate folder in web app published folder. (1. Uncheck Zip Published projects option 2. Add Copy File task to copy web jobs' build result  to appropriate folder in web app published folder 3. Add Archive Files task 4. Add Publish Artifact task)

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT is it possible that something changed regarding the "App_Data/..." folder. I am experiencing that this folder is not there anymore.